# RDLC report, How to combine the bottom of tablix with page footer

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

Help me please.
A Tablix has  7 rows but I need to increase height of tablix until it matches the footer.
What should I do?

[image]

[Edited.]

According to below figure, I tried to insert a lot of blank rows to a Tablix. 
And I used an Expression for setting visibility each row.
Example :

-If Dataset has one record. One Blank row will hide.

-If Dataset has two records. Two Blank rows will hide.

But It is inflexible because some rows aren't a single Line.

[image]

Comment: Potentially silly question but... I there a reason you're not using an actual footer for the report?

Comment: This is actual footer. I inserted it by right click then choose "Add page footer."

Answer (score 2):

**Using RDLC 2005** you can simulate this behaviour with:

- a `Body` section with `Body.Height = Page.Height - Footer.Height - TopMargin - BottomMargin`
- a `Tablix` without border
- a `Rectangle` for every column to simulate with `Rectangle.Height = Body.Height`; set its `RepeatWith` property to `Tablix`

In order to simplify some operations you could put your `Total` textbox in the `Footer` or consider it when you build your `Body` section as explained before.

There is an example of what I mean (`Tablix` with red border and `Rectangle` with black border):

[image]

Comment: Do you have the  Example?
I don't understand, How to set a  a propertied of the report 's control.
It set a height  by xml coding? Or input values to the properties via user interface (right-side of a windows).

Comment: To set a .Size you have to display Properties windows and left click (or right click) on a object. Please note that to display Report properties (page size and margins) you have to right click on the grey area outside your page; to display Body properties you have to click on a blank point without controls.

Comment: Has it dynamic method?

Comment: I have some question about three step above. How to simulate a rectangle. I don't understand? if I input to properties directly such as Rectangle.Height = 10cm But A4  paper 's height 21cm.So if Dataset has only two row it will make two page.

Comment: sorry, it seems that this method works only with the good old rdlc 2005 `Table`. With the latest version `RepeatWith` property works differently. Maybe there is a workaround but you can also design this report in 2005 (using a free tool as My-FyiReporting
) and display it in a 201x project.

Comment: How to repeat rectangles in each page?

Answer (score 1):

Another, though more complicated way, of forcing the height would be to use Subreports for each of the columns.

Each Subreport would list the table contents for that column as a single list.

You could then force height of a single table row to reach the footer... If the Subreport does not require the entire space it will return whitespace

Parent Report

[image]

Report 5

[image]

Report 4

[image]

Results in the following output report

[image]

Comment: just a note: if [Subject] is very long and occupy two or more rows, [ABC] won't be aligned anymore.

Comment: I like your answer. It 's work for me. But if my Dataset has a lot of records.
More than one page.  I am not sure it's work.